# How to say "May your new year be full of happiness"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, usage

It's New Year Day, and you want to wish your friend

> May your new year be full of happiness and success.

Do you say

> Möge dein neues Jahr voller Glück und Erfolg sein

? I'm not sure if "möge" is correct or make it sound too formal here.

You can say

> Ich wünsche dir ein neues Jahr voller Glück und Erfolg.

which conveys the same sense, but wouldn't be a direct translation.

Also, any suggestions for other ways to say this?

Comment: Das Wort *möge* ist in Ordnung an der Stelle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your suggestions are indeed correct. However your question was what you would actually say to your friend on new years eve. I therefore assume you're looking for something that is commonly used.

"Möge dein neues Jahr voller Glück und Erfolg sein" sounds too formal to me. It's not something someone would naturally say.
Actually, it sounds just like it would sound if you would lead a comparable sentence with the word "may" in English. It sounds artificial and is reminiscent of Star Wars' *may the force be with you*.

The second one is fine, still a somewhat formal way of putting it.

Some alternative suggestions, more natural-sounding to my ears:

1. "Ich wünsche Dir ein frohes neues Jahr!"
2. "Frohes neues Jahr!" or "Frohes Neues!" (colloquial, but VERY common)

Answer (score 4):

Deine Vorschläge klingen gut und klingen sehr gehoben. Ich würde sie nur für sehr gute Freunde/Familienmitglieder benutzen.

Der Standardsatz, den man überall benutzen kann, ist:

> Ich wünsche dir/Ihnen ein gesundes, neues Jahr!

Verkürzt wird auch oft `Gesundes, neues Jahr!` oder einfach nur `Gesundes Neues!` gesagt.

Alle drei Varianten werden nur im neuen Jahr, also direkt nach Mitternacht bis in die ersten Januartage hinein, benutzt.

In den letzten Dezembertagen bis direkt vor Mitternacht sagt man oft:

> `Ich wünsche dir einen guten Rutsch ins neue Jahr!`

Answer (score 0):

Both of your suggestions are correct and sound good.