# Translation of “May all your dreams and wishes come true”

Tags: translation, english-to-german

You want to say to your friend on her birthday

> May all your dreams and wishes come true.

A direct translation would be

> (a) Mögen all deine Träume und Wünsche wahr werden.

But as it was pointed out in [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18348/how-to-say-may-your-new-year-be-full-of-happiness), saying *möge* is too formal. A suggestion with *Ich wünsche* was made, which in this case would be

> (b) Ich wünsche dir, dass all deine Träume und Wünsche wahr werden.

However, the repeated use of *wünsche* makes the sentence seem awkward.

What would be a good way to translate this?

Comment: To me, both are fine (except: mögen (plural). The "mögen" is okay since it is a festive context. I'm voting close as I think it's opinion based

Comment: @Emanuel Don't you feel that the second sentence is awkward for the reason I mentioned? (By the way, I don't feel that this question is more opinion-based than several other translation-type questions.)

Comment: No, I can perfectly imagine myself saying this in a festive tone t my best friend and then burping without being ironic. As for opinion based or not... well, I'll just give an answer then.

Comment: @Emanuel Also, your suggestion that "mögen" is okay since it is a festive context contradicts both answers in the linked question, which is also in a festive context. An explanation on that would be nice. :)

Comment: Phew... hard to explain. To me, a new year is nowhere near as special as a birthday. The birthday only belongs to my friend. It's HIS day. New years is everybody's day and I don't find it very festive. More like "party"-ive. Little caveat added to my answer. You'll hate it.

Comment: wünsche-Wünsche: one of the rare occasions where it wouldn't bother me at all.

Comment: Since *all deine Träume und Wünsche* is plural, *mögen* should be plural, too. I just corrected it ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a native speaker I would say that (a) doesn't sound too formal at all.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, both are fine in that context.
Caveat: I would not use the "mögen"-version if me and the person are using formal-you. Then it would sound too emphatic and could be perceived as irony.

Answer (score 1):

They are both fine but it's more common to say

> Mögen all deine Träume und Wünsche in Erfüllung gehen!